# how to check wso2 api manager version

Tags: wso2, api-manager

I'm using the api manager with the default port

```
https://hostname:9443/publisher/apis
```

which was installed by my coworker, he happened to be unreachable and I need to know the version of the wso2 api manager? any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Few options available.

1. In the footer section of the publisher, you should see the API Manager version.
2. You can log into https://hostname:9443/carbon
3. You can try https://hostname:9443/carbon/product/about.html

Comment: I wont suggest use 3. option. On My WSO2API-Manager 3.1.0 it shows 2.6.0
Another option is to use:
`https://hostname:9443/services/Version`